# moq file not found exception system.xml when accessing the mocked object

Tags: c#, exception, moq

I am getting a file not found exception for this code:
(System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.)

```
public interface ISocket
{
    int Receive(byte[] buffer);
}

    [Test]
    public void ShouldMock()
    {
        var Mock = new Mock<ISocket>();
        ToBeTested Example = new ToBeTested ((ISocket)Mock.Object);
    }
```

I can not find my error and in no case i ever referenced a system.xml. What could have gone wrong?

EDIT:

I did never solve this problem and i am still stuck with manual mocking. I tried once again to set up a project that uses moq but failed again. Here is some other code with the same runtime error message:

```
    [Test]
    public void shouldLoadContextBasedOn_Type_AfterGettingContextDictionary()
    {
        Type loadableType = typeof(Context_Empty);
        var mocklib= new Mock<IDictionary<Type, Type>>();
        mocklib.SetupGet(lib => lib[loadableType]).Returns(loadableType);

        ContextLoader tested = new ContextLoader();
        tested.setContextKnowledge(mocklib.Object);
        tested.loadContext(loadableType);

        IContextBase expected = new mockContext();
        IContextBase actual = tested.getCurrentContext();

        mocklib.VerifyGet( lib => lib[typeof(Context_Empty)]);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.ToString(), actual.ToString());
    }
```

The stacktray shows that moq is looking for its source before killing itself - is that it? Does it actually only work if i have the source installed under d:\Code\moq\src\Source ? This does not seem rigth. (EDIT: amd it wasnt - nunit just informed me that i can not find the files, so nothing to do with the error)

Do i have the right package? I chose silverligth4 and i am using both dlls i found in there - the others did not work because something was missing.

EDIT:

To illustrate the problem even sharper. hiere is another failing piece of code:

```
    [Test]
    public void mockDemo()
    {
        var crappy = new Mock<IDisposable>();
        IDisposable instance = crappy.Object; //Runtime Error
    }
```

And here isthe stacktrace - manual rewritten, typingerror may occur

```
ContextLoader_Spec mockDemo()
Mock1 get_Object()
Mock1 OnGetObject()
Mock1 InitialiseInstance()
PexProtector Invoke()
Mock1 <InitializeInstance>b_32()
ProxyGenerator CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget()
DefaultProxyBuilder CreateInterfaceProxyTypeWithoutTarget()
InterfaceProxyWithTargetGenerator GenerateCode()
InterfaceProxyWithoutTargetGenerator GenerateType()
InterfaceProxyWithTargetGenerator Init()
InterfaceProxyWithTargetGenerator CreateFields()
```

I dont know why this exception happens.

EDIT: This seems to be a [known issue withSilverlight4](http://www.mail-archive.com/castle-project-users@googlegroups.com/msg09582.html)
EDIT: Retried with the other versions NET35/NET40/NET40Castle/Silverlight4 - all show the same error.

Comment: Looks like ToBeTested constructor may be referring a dll. Problem may be with that part of the code.

Comment: Why are you casting to ISocket? Shouldn't the ToBesTested constructor accecpt an ISocket type instead of an ISocket implementation???

Comment: Your test with `IDisposable` works just fine on my machine (tried in .Net 4 console app)

Comment: can you send me your whole project folder? maybe it is my setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to Rhino works like a charm.
[Rhino can be downloadad](http://builds.hibernatingrhinos.com/builds/Rhino-Mocks) seperately or is in the lib folder of your [nunit testframework](http://nunit.sourcearchive.com/).

All you have to do is switch your project properties from the .Net Client profile to the pure .Net Profile and you are good to go.

Here is a Testsnippet that helps you control if you have done it.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Rhino.Mocks;

namespace Test.selftest
{
    [TestFixture]
    class Framework_Test
    {
        [Test]
        public void ShouldCompileAndExecuteASimpleNUnitTest()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldVerifyRhinoMock()
        {
            ICloneable mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICloneable>();
            mock.Expect(x => x.Clone()).Return(new Object()).Repeat.Times(1);
            mock.Clone();
            mock.VerifyAllExpectations();
        }
    }
}
```